# Questions on creating a service that connects automatically to a BLE device on android

Tags: android, service, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am implementing a service that uses the `autoconnect` feature of `bluetoothGatt` to connect to the device and monitor it while it is being connected.

I work on the assumption that the device is already bonded (a coworker is responsible for that part) so autoconnect should not have any problems

my code is as follows:

```
//the callback is for the class I have created that actually does the connection
class BTService: Service(), CoroutineScope, BTConnection.Callback {
    private val btReceiver by lazy { BluetoothStateReceiver(this::btStateChange) } //receiver for bt adapter changes

    private var connection:BTConnection? = null
    private var readJob:Job? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        buildNotificationChannels()
        registerReceiver(btReceiver, IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) //since I can't register this receiver in AndroidManifest any more I did it here
    }

    private fun btStateChange(enabled: Boolean) {
        if (enabled)
            startConnecting()
        else
            stopConnection()
    }

    private fun startConnecting() {
        
        val address = prefs.address //get the current saved address
        val current = connection //get the current connection

        //try to stop the current connection if it is different than the one we want to set up
        if (current != null && !current.address.equals(address, true))
            current.stop()

        if (address.isNullOrBlank())
            return
        //then we create a new connection if needed
        val new = if (current == null || !current.address.equals(address, true)) {
            Injections.buildConnection(application, address, this)
        } else {
            current
        }
        connection = new
        new.connect()
    }

    //this is one of the callbacks from BTConnection.Callback
    override fun connected(address: String) {
        if (address != connection?.address) return
        val cn = connection ?: return
        showConnectionNotification()
        val notification = buildForegroundNotification()
        startForeground(FOREGROUND_ID, notification)
        readJob?.cancel()
        readJob = launch {
             cn.dataFlow //this is a flow that will be emmitting read data
             .cancellable() 
             .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
             .buffer()
             .onEach(this@BTService::parseData)
             .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)
        }
    }


    private suspend fun parseData(bytes:ByteArray) { //this is where the parsing and storage etc happens
}

private fun stopConnection() {
    val cn = connection
    connection = null
    cn?.stop()
}
 
override fun disconnected(address: String) { //another callback from the connection class
    showDisconnectNotification()
    stopForeground(true)
}
```

my code that stops the connection is

```
fun stop() {
    canceled = true
    if (connected)
        gatt?.disconnect()
    launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        delay(1000)
        gatt?.close()
        gatt = null
    }
}
```

my code is based (and affected) by this really good article I read:

https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-2-47a3cdaade07

I have also created a receiver for boot events that will call

```
 context.startService(Intent(context, BTService::class.java))
```

just to make sure that the service is created at least once and the bt receiver is registered

my questions are:

a) is there a chance that my service will be destroyed while it is not in foreground mode? i.e. when the device is not near by and bluetoothGat.connect is suspending while autoconnecting? is it enough for me to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand() to make sure that even when my service is destroyed it will start again?

b) if there is such a case, is there a way to at least recreate the service so the btReceiver is at least registered?

c) when should `close()` be called on bluetoothGatt in case of autoconnect = true? only when creating a new connection (in my example where I call Injections.buildConnection)? do I also call it when the bluetoothadapter is disabled? or can I reuse the same connection and bluetoothGatt if the user turns the bluetooth adapter off and on again?

d) is there a way to find out if autoconnect has failed and will not try again? and is there a way to actually test and reproduce such an effect? the article mentioned above says it can happen **when the batteries of the peripheral are almost empty, or when you are on the edge of the Bluetooth range**

thanks in advance for any help you can provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a-b) If your app does not have an activity or a service that is in the foreground, the system may kill it at anytime. Pending or active BLE connections doesn't affect the system's point of view when to kill the app whatsoever. (When it comes to *scanning* for advertisements, the story is completely different though.)

The general approach to make sure autoConnects stay alive is to have a foreground service running at all the time. So don't stop it while the device is currently not connected, if you want to have a pending connection. There is no point in using Job Scheduler, WorkManagers etc. since having a foreground service should be enough to keep the app process alive, and pending/active connections are kept alive as long as the app is. The app does not use any cpu% at all when waiting for pending BLE connections. However some Chinese phone makers are known to not follow the Android documentation, by sometimes killing apps even though they have running foreground services.

c) Each BluetoothGatt object represents and refers to an object inside the Bluetooth process running on the same phone. By default the system allows a total of 32 such objects (last time I checked). In order to release these precious resources, you call `close()`. If you forget, you will have a leak, meaning your app or some other app might not be able to create a BluetoothGatt object. (When app processes exit, their BluetoothGatt objects are however closed automatically). The API is a bit strangely designed, that there is both a `disconnect` method and a `close` method. But anyway, the `disconnect` method gracefully initiates a disconnection of the connection and you will then get an `onConnectionStateChange` callback telling when the disconnection is complete. You must however call `close` in order to free the resource, or call `connect` if you'd like to re-connect, or you can take an action a bit later. Calling `close` on a connected BluetoothGatt object will also disconnect, but you won't get any callback due to the object is being destroyed at the same time.

Since all BluetoothGatt objects represents objects in the Bluetooth process, these will "die" or stop working when you turn off Bluetooth, since that involves shutting down the Bluetooth process. This means you need to recreate all BluetoothGatt objects when Bluetooth is restarted. You can call `close` on the old objects, but it won't do anything since they're dead. Since the documentation doesn't say anything about this, I suggest you call `close` anyway to be on the safe side if the behaviour is changed in the future.

d) To detect if a `connectGatt` call fails and will not try again, you can listen to the `onConnectionStateChange` callback. If this gives an error code, such as 257, it usually means that the system has reached maximum number of connections, or maximum number of some resource. You can test this out by simply initiating pending connections to a bunch of different Bluetooth device addresses.

I would not trust the statement that new connection attempts would be aborted if the peripheral is low on battery or being on the "edge of Bluetooth range". I'd be glad to see a pin point to Android's Bluetooth source code where this happens, since I really believe this is not true at all.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are intending to distribute your app to Google Play Store, you need to be targeting minimum api level 29 if I'm not mistaken, hence you should be using either JobService along with JobScheduler or [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager), instead of Service. This is to support the background limitations from Oreo(26) onwards.

a) if you properly implement any of the two options I mentioned above, you can write a proper service that will not terminate unless you stop it. Here are some resources on JobService : ([resource1](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background), [resource2](https://itnext.io/migrate-your-app-to-android-oreo-e0fa794b1d21), [resource3](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html))

b) You can re-register as you please upon the onStartJob() method of your JobService, which will recreate your app.

c) Each time you are done with the peripheral ble device, you need to close the gatt connection with it. Here is a snippet from the BluetoothGatt class

```
/**
 * Close this Bluetooth GATT client.
 *
 * Application should call this method as early as possible after it is done with
 * this GATT client.
 */
public void close() {
```

Also, from the BluetoothAdapter class javadoc, you can see that all the connections are terminated gracefully when ble is disabled.

```
 /**
 * Turn off the local Bluetooth adapter&mdash;do not use without explicit
 * user action to turn off Bluetooth.
 * <p>This gracefully shuts down all Bluetooth connections, stops Bluetooth
 * system services, and powers down the underlying Bluetooth hardware.
 * <p class="caution"><strong>Bluetooth should never be disabled without
 * direct user consent</strong>. The {@link #disable()} method is
 * provided only for applications that include a user interface for changing
 * system settings, such as a "power manager" app.</p>
 * <p>This is an asynchronous call: it will return immediately, and
 * clients should listen for {@link #ACTION_STATE_CHANGED}
 * to be notified of subsequent adapter state changes. If this call returns
 * true, then the adapter state will immediately transition from {@link
 * #STATE_ON} to {@link #STATE_TURNING_OFF}, and some time
 * later transition to either {@link #STATE_OFF} or {@link
 * #STATE_ON}. If this call returns false then there was an
 * immediate problem that will prevent the adapter from being turned off -
 * such as the adapter already being turned off.
 *
 * @return true to indicate adapter shutdown has begun, or false on immediate error
 */
@RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN)
public boolean disable() {
```

d) I am not sure on what callback will be triggered. To reproduce, the two items you mentioned seem like valid cases to try.

I hope this helps you perfect your project!